# How to access the nth element in an array of structures

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I have a program that requires me to create a structure that holds students' info. The requirements say to use a pointer and dynamically allocate an array of the StudentInfo structure. For now, I just want to store an ID number for each student. I think I am storing the numbers properly, but when I try to display the ID numbers, I run into problems.

```
using namespace std;

struct StudentInfo
{
    string Name = "";
    int Idnum = 0;
    int* Tests = { 0 };
    double Average = 0.0;
    char Grade = 'z';
};

int main() {

    int numberOfStudents = 0,
        numberOfTests = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> numberOfStudents; 
    cout << "Enter the number of tests: ";
    cin >> numberOfTests;

    StudentInfo* students = nullptr;
    students = new StudentInfo[numberOfStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the student ID: ";
        cin >> students[i].Idnum;
    }

    cout << students[2]->Idnum;
    
    return 0;
}
```

So for example, lets say I have 3 students and the id numbers are 123, 456, 789 respectively. How would I get the cout statement to show me 789?

Edit:
compiler error listed below:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Chap11Num12, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Chap11Num12.cpp
1>C:\Users\mstew\Desktop\CIS2541\week10\Chap11Num12\Chap11Num12.cpp(41,21): error C2819: type 'StudentInfo' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
1>C:\Users\mstew\Desktop\CIS2541\week10\Chap11Num12\Chap11Num12.cpp(14): message : see declaration of 'StudentInfo'
1>C:\Users\mstew\Desktop\CIS2541\week10\Chap11Num12\Chap11Num12.cpp(41,21): message : did you intend to use '.' instead?
1>C:\Users\mstew\Desktop\CIS2541\week10\Chap11Num12\Chap11Num12.cpp(41,28): error C2232: '->StudentInfo::Idnum': left operand has 'struct' type, use '.'
1>Done building project "Chap11Num12.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You do `cin >> students[i].Idnum;` to read a new `Idnum` in and it works, but `cout << students[3]->Idnum;` to output one and get errors. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: `cout << students[3]->Idnum;` -- How do you access the 3rd element of any array, whether it is an array of `int`, `double`, `char` or `StudentInfo`?  This: `int main() { int arr[] = {10,20,30}; }`.  How do you print the third value, `30` in that array?

Comment: scohe001, sorry, that was a typo and I fixed it. I know it was trying to access an out of bounds element.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, I am not sure I understand your question. If it was a simple int arr[] I would use subscripts like I am trying to do here.

Comment: It isn't just about subscripts -- it's the value of the subscript you are using.  That's why I asked the question -- you had a `3`.  Also, why didn't you post the compiler error you received?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the element being out of bounds. It's the difference between `.` and `->`

Comment: Nathan Pierson, I see. Changing that fixed it, but I don't understand why. According to my text book "s->m -- s is a structure pointer and m is a member. This expression accesses the m member of the structure pointed to by s."

Comment: @The_Redhawk -- Please post the actual compiler error message, and someone will walk you step by step as to how to understand what it was stating.

Comment: `students[2]` is a `StudentInfo` struct, not a `StudentInfo*` pointer.

Comment: I'm trying to get the compiler error to post it here.

Comment: Those error messages actually seem pretty informative to me and point you to the correct fix for your problem.

Comment: True, I guess I should have looked closer at them, but the red squiggly error lines tilted me. I roughly see the overall lesson here. I am still slightly confused then on how the -> would come into play then though

Comment: It would come into play if you had a pointer to a `StudentInfo` struct that you wanted to act on. (Yes, `students` is a variable of type `StudentInfo*`, but you're using it as an array, not as a pointer to the first element of the array.) Right now there's nothing in your code that would especially make sense as pointers, so it would be a bit contrived to come up with an example of how `->` would be used.

Comment: That helps a bit. One of the members of the StudentInfo structure also a pointer but I guess I will cross that bridge when I get there.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: students[2] is not a pointer, therefore use student[2].Idnum. Or students+2 is a pointer, use (students+2)->Idnum.